# Expand the error list with shortcut in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to expand the errors list using a keyboard shortcut but with no luck. Is there any way to expand the list without using a mouse? I'm using Eclipse Indigo.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The <kbd>*</kbd> expands all while <kbd>+</kbd> expands 1 level and it works for all the lists I think. It is useful in the package explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. It's just simply <kbd>*</kbd> (asterisk).

To fold one level: <kbd>-</kbd>

To collapse all: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>